# What do triangle above or below the note mean?

Tags: notation, articulation

[image: the triangles in question]

I was practicing some piano music (Ein Spanier Fur Elise to be exact) and I got to a bit in the music where the sheet music showed triangle above/below the note. They could be either just below, just above, or even both.

I have not seen these symbols before and there for do not know how to play them.

Answer (score 2):

Staccatissimo - not just short like staccato, but **more** detached and played with greater space between pitches.

Answer (score 0):

Staccatissimo. Like a staccato, but shorter, around a quarter of the written note length. So, over/under a crotchet, as here, you play a note a semiquaver long, leaving a dotted quaver of silence to follow, before the next note.

Comment: And is there any difference between it being above the note or bellow or both?

Comment: None at all. But don't shout!